# How to close peerConnection in WebRtc

Tags: webrtc, getusermedia

[WebRtc sample](http://googlechrome.github.io/webrtc/samples/web/content/peerconnection/audio/)

If I press call, allow/deny menu is shown in the upper screen. When I press allow, Chrome starts displaying red circle in the header which signals that microphone is active. All other sounds in others Chromes tabs are muted (for example youtube video).

When I press hang, red circle does not dissapears, youtube video in second tab is still muted. I have to press F5 to restore state which was before call.

Is there any PeerConnection to stop the call and stop mic recording ?

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the reason the "red light" is still on is that the media tracks in the mediaStream object (called `localstream` on that particular page) gathered through `getusermedia` is still playing/active.

To close a media stream and thus release any hold on the local media inputs simply call `localstream.stop()` that will end the stream and stop accessing the local media input. This will stop all associated media tracks.

You can also do this by calling `stop()` on the individual media tracks(grabbed from `getVideoTracks` or `getAudioTracks` from the `mediaStream`).

As for other audio being turned down in other pages/apps. [Here is the crbug handling that issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376796).

Side Note: if the media is being pushed through a peerConnection, then you will probably have to renegotiate the connection due to the `mediaStream` changing.

Comment: The funny thing - if I stop localStream, I can see that "red light" is removed, however youtube video in another chrome tab is still muted. Only F5 helps